# How do i integrate Cometchat with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i installed Cometchat but have no idea how to configure the integration.php  to work with wordpress. Does anyone have any knowledge on cometchat wordpress installations?

in particular the integration.php file

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php



/* ADVANCED */

define('SET_SESSION_NAME','');          // Session name
define('DO_NOT_START_SESSION','0');     // Set to 1 if you have already started the session
define('DO_NOT_DESTROY_SESSION','0');   // Set to 1 if you do not want to destroy session on logout
define('ADD_LAST_ACTIVITY','1');        // Do not touch
define('SWITCH_ENABLED','0');       
define('INCLUDE_JQUERY','1');   
define('FORCE_MAGIC_QUOTES','1');
define('FORCE_ALL_USERS','1');

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* DATABASE */

include_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."wp-load.php";

// DO NOT EDIT DATABASE VALUES BELOW
// DO NOT EDIT DATABASE VALUES BELOW
// DO NOT EDIT DATABASE VALUES BELOW

define('DB_SERVER',                 DB_HOST                                 );
define('DB_PORT',                   "3306"                                  );
define('DB_USERNAME',               DB_USER                                 );
define('TABLE_PREFIX',              $table_prefix                           );
define('DB_USERTABLE',              "users"                                 );
define('DB_USERTABLE_USERID',       "ID"                                    );
define('DB_USERTABLE_NAME',         "display_name"                          );
define('DB_AVATARTABLE',            " "                                     );
define('DB_AVATARFIELD',            " CONCAT(".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID.",'|',".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".user_email)");
define('DB_USERTABLE_LASTACTIVITY', "lastactivity"                          );

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* FUNCTIONS */

function getUserID() {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    $userid = 0;

    if (!empty($_SESSION['basedata']) && $_SESSION['basedata'] != 'null') {
        $_REQUEST['basedata'] = $_SESSION['basedata'];
    }

    if (!empty($_REQUEST['basedata'])) {
        $userid = $_REQUEST['basedata'];
    }

    if (!empty($current_user->ID)) {
        $userid = $current_user->ID;
    }

    return $userid;
}

function chatLogin($userName,$userPass){
    $userid = 0;
    include(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."wp-includes".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."class-phpass.php");
    $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, false);   

    if (filter_var($userName, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $sql ="SELECT * FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE." WHERE user_email='".$userName."'"; 
    } else {
        $sql ="SELECT * FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE." WHERE user_login='".$userName."'"; 
    }

    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );        
    $check = $hasher->CheckPassword($userPass, $row['user_pass']);  

    if ($check) { 
        $userid = $row['ID'];
    }

    return $userid;
}

function getFriendsList($userid,$time) {

    $sql = ("select DISTINCT ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." userid, ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_NAME." username, ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_LASTACTIVITY." lastactivity, ".DB_AVATARFIELD." avatar, ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".user_nicename link, cometchat_status.message, cometchat_status.status from ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE." left join cometchat_status on ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." = cometchat_status.userid ".DB_AVATARTABLE." where ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." <> '".mysql_real_escape_string($userid)."' and ('".$time."'-".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_LASTACTIVITY." < '".((ONLINE_TIMEOUT)*2)."') order by username asc");

    return $sql;
}

function getUserDetails($userid) {
    $sql = ("select ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." userid, ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_NAME." username, ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_LASTACTIVITY." lastactivity,  ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".user_nicename link, ".DB_AVATARFIELD." avatar, cometchat_status.message, cometchat_status.status from ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE." left join cometchat_status on ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." = cometchat_status.userid ".DB_AVATARTABLE." where ".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE.".".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." = '".mysql_real_escape_string($userid)."'");
    return $sql;
}

function updateLastActivity($userid) {
    $sql = ("update `".TABLE_PREFIX.DB_USERTABLE."` set ".DB_USERTABLE_LASTACTIVITY." = '".getTimeStamp()."' where ".DB_USERTABLE_USERID." = '".mysql_real_escape_string($userid)."'");
    return $sql;
}

function getUserStatus($userid) {
     $sql = ("select cometchat_status.message, cometchat_status.status from cometchat_status where userid = '".mysql_real_escape_string($userid)."'");
     return $sql;
}

function getLink($link) {
    return '';
}

function getAvatar($data) {

    $data = explode('|',$data);
    $id = $data[0];

    return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'.md5($data[1]).'?d=wavatar&s=80';
}


function getTimeStamp() {
    return current_time('timestamp');
}

function processTime($time) {
    return $time;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* HOOKS */

function hooks_statusupdate($userid,$statusmessage) {

}

function hooks_forcefriends() {

}

function hooks_activityupdate($userid,$status) {

}

function hooks_message($userid,$unsanitizedmessage) {

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: That's actually... really useful. Client bought the wrong CC license a while back and this converts it perfectly.